# Unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hidden

Tags: javascript, magento, navigation

I am having some js error in Magento, more specifically the code bellow is part of a navigation that should show all the elements via a load more button. All the settings are also send via ajax. Part of the code is bellow.

```
 showAllNavigationAttribute: function(control, request_var){
        $(control).up('ol').select('li:hidden').each(
                function (e) {
                    e.show();
                }
            );
        $(control).up('li').hide();
        this.navigationOpenFilters[request_var + '_show_all'] = true;
    },
```

And this is the full error report

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hidden
    at Function.Sizzle.error (prototype.js:5265)
    at PSEUDO (prototype.js:5535)
    at matcherFromTokens (prototype.js:6010)
    at Sizzle.compile (prototype.js:6133)
    at Sizzle.select (prototype.js:6208)
    at Sizzle (prototype.js:4770)
    at Object.select (prototype.js:6296)
    at select (prototype.js:2661)
    at HTMLOListElement._methodized (prototype.js:456)
    at klass.showAllNavigationAttribute (advanced-navigation.js:1299)
```

The code above is part of the advanced-navigation.js

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue with searching for the `display:none` on the elements and replaced line like so

```
$(control).up('ol').select("li[style*='display:none']").each(
```